# How to get the response data outside the post method in node js

Tags: node.js, post, response

USER.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const user = express.Router();
var username='';
app.use(bodyParser.json());
user.post('/',  (req, res) => {
    let First_Name = req.body.First_Name;
    // This SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameters in this. 
    let query = "INSERT INTO `user` (First_Name) VALUES ('" + First_Name + "')";
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) { 
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send('Success');
        console.log(result);
        console.log('User Created successfully !');
        username=First_Name;
    })
})


module.exports = {user:user};
```

Middle.js

```
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const middle = express.Router();
const {user}= require('./USER');
middle.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    //doing some code
    const username = 'here i need to use the username i get from user.js page';
    });
    module.exports = {middle:middle};
```

SERVER.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const {user}= require('./routes/USER');
const {middle}= require('./routes/Middle');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/add', user);// here i am adding the user 
app.use('/middle', middle);// here i need to call the middle which uses the username entered in user post
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.json('Working!'));

// Basic 404 handler
app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('Not Found');
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

Here in middle.js file, i want to use the username get it from the user.js page.

When a user enters the first name in react pages and submitted it is inserted into a database in USER.js page. I need to call the first_name from USER.js to the Middle.js page. I am calling both the apis in server.js page. How to maintain the workflow, like once the user inserted that value sends to middle post and doing some other functionality something like inserting into a .txt file?

Comment: Can you format your code, it is hard to read

Comment: edited the code

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code, and someone might be able to use a malformed `First_Name` in order to inject a `DELETE user` command into your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a simple solution to your problem, you wish to save *username* so you can use it in another function.

The reason *username* is undefined in your

```
console.log(username);// i need the variable here after insert outside function
```

line is that it will run on startup. So the POST has not occurred yet and of course the variable is not populated.

You need to remember I/O in Node.js is asynchronous. So the user.post(...) handler will not block the main thread.

**NB: As @halfer pointed out, the SQL query you are using is a serious security risk. The First_Name should be passed as a query parameter.**

The best way to deal with this is to pass username to another handler function.

I've also added an example of setting req.user in the user route.

Like below:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const user = express.Router();
var username='';
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(user);
app.use(middleware);

user.post('/',  (req, res, next) => {
    let First_Name = req.body.First_Name;
    // This SQL query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameters in this. 
    let query = "INSERT INTO `user` (First_Name) VALUES ('" + First_Name + "')";
    db.query(query, (err, result) => {
        if (err) { 
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.send('Success');
        console.log(result);
        console.log('User Created successfully !');
        username=First_Name;
        userHandler(username);
        req.user = username;
        next();
    })
})

function middleware(req, res, next) {
    console.log("middleware: user:", req.user);
    next();
}

// Use this function to do whatever you wish with the user.
function userHandler(username) {
    console.log(`userHandler: Doing stuff with user: ${username}...`);
    /* Do whatever with the username variable... */
}


app.listen(7070);
```

Comment: This answer looks helpful, but appears to replicate the SQL injection vulnerability in the OP. I think we should always try to remark on these, especially when producing an answer that replicates that issue.

Comment: Thanks @Terry Lennox. I am able to fetch username only on the same page. when I am using module.exports(userHandler); in user.js page and try to use username in server.js page, I am not able to fetch the username. can you please help me on this.

Comment: Have you looked at setting a request object property for the user in your post handler? If the request property is used later in the server. For example: req.user = { username } ? Or you could create a function getUser() in your user module like so: function getUser() { return username; }. As long as you call this _after_ the post it will work.

Comment: You should be able to add the user details to your request object in the user.js module. e.g req.user = username. Your middleware should then be able to access this object. I'm assuming your middleware will be called after the user route, e.g. use next() in your user route handler.

Comment: I have passed the parameter next as user.post('/',  (req, res, next) because it was showing error as next() is not defined. after this I am getting the error "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client". It will be great if you can tell me how to use username in middle.js with next() instead of in same user.js page.

Comment: Oh, yes, apologies, I forgot to add the next parameter, I'll update to include thus. I think you get this error if you call res.send twice. So if you're calling res.send (or similar) in your middleware this could be the cause.

Comment: Thanks, @TerryLennox. If I am using middleware() in user.js as you have mentioned above, still I am getting this error.

Comment: Could you try removing the res.send from user.js and see what happens? Thank you!

Comment: now issue is solved after removing res.send. but i am not able to see the output of console.log("middleware: user:", req.user);. How to use middleware function in middle.js page?

Comment: i am calling post() in function middleware() in user.js page. it is not allowing me to do that throwing me error. Is that we can't use post() inside another function?

Comment: You should be able to use app.post(middleware) to only access the middleware on post requests, try creating middleware like so:                                                          function middle (req, res, next) {
    //doing some code
    const username = 'here i need to use the username i get from user.js page';
};
module.exports = {middle:middle};    Then do app.post(middle); in your server.js to use this middleware!

Comment: i was using this wayfunction middle (req, res, next) { //doing some code const username = 'here i need to use the username i get from user.js page'; }; module.exports = {middle:middle}; earlier but i was unable to get the req.user value in middle().